# onChange update very slowly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a modal, inside the modal I have FormControl:

```
<FormGroup>
      <span>Target</span>
      <FormControl id={this.getbackground(account)}
          type="text"
          defaultValue={this.getMyNewTargetAsString(lp, account, button_state)}
          value={this.getTargetValue(account_id)}
          onChange={this.onTargetChange.bind(this, account_id)}/>
</FormGroup>
```

The onChange method:

```
onTargetChange: function (account_id, e) {
  _account_target[["target", account_id]] = parseInt(e.target.value);
},
```

The getMyNewTargetAsString method:

```
getMyNewTargetAsString : function (lp, account, button_state) {
if (lp == undefined || account== undefined || button_state == undefined) {
  return 0;
}
if (button_state == "on") {
  return 0;
} else {
  var new_target = Math.floor(lp * this.props.size);
  return new_target;
  }
},
```

The getTargetValue method:

```
getTargetValue: function (account_id) {
  return _account_target[["target", account_id]];
},
```

The getbackground method:

```
getbackground : function (account) {
if (account == undefined) {
  return "targetStyle";
}
if (Math.abs(account.size) > 100) {
  return "targetWerrning";
}
 return "targetStyle";

},
```

when I running my app and I am changing the target the change is very very slow (each character I adds takes a second or two).

Is there any idea of what can be the slow factor?


I am using JavaScript, React and bootstrap (the modal is trigger by a button from a bootstrap table), the app is part of my spring boot jar.

---

**UPDATE**:
The problem is with the onChange={this.onTargetChange.bind(this, account_id)}
in REACT is bad practice to use bind inside the render.
when you use bind in the render it make the code to run very slowly.

Comment: Can you also post this.getbackground(account), this.getMyNewTargetAsString(lp, account, button_state), this.getTargetValue(account_id) functions code?

Comment: I add the functions code